# How to make this crawler more efficient

Tags: php, performance, web-scraping, web-crawler

I built this web crawler.

https://github.com/shoutweb/WebsiteCrawlerEmailExtractor

```
//Regular expression function that scans individual pages for emails
    function get_emails_from_webpage($url)
    {
      $text=file_get_contents($url);
      $res = preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9\.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/i",$text,$matches);
      if ($res) {
          return array_unique($matches[0]);
      }
      else{
          return null;
      }
    }

//URL Array
$URLArray = array();

//Inputted URL right now it just pulls it from a GET variable but you can do alter this any way you want
$inputtedURL = $_GET['url'];


//Crawling the inputted domain to get the URLS
$urlContent = file_get_contents("http://".urldecode($inputtedURL));
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($urlContent);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

$scrapedEmails = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++){
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    //array_push($scrapedEmails, $hrefs->length);
    // validate url
    if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false){
        if (strpos($url, $inputtedURL) !== false) {
                array_push($URLArray, $url);
            }

    }
}

//Extracting the emails from URLS that were crawled
foreach ($URLArray as $key => $url) {
    $emails = get_emails_from_webpage($url);

    if($emails != null){
      foreach($emails as $email) {
          if(!in_array($email, $scrapedEmails)){
            array_push($scrapedEmails,$email);
        }
      }
    } 
}


//Ouputting the scraped emails in addition to the the number of URLS crawled
foreach($scrapedEmails as $value) {
    echo $value . " " . count($URLArray);
}
```

It basically goes to a domain that you enter, gets all the pages, and then checks to see if there is an email.

Each domain can take up to 30 seconds to crawl. I want to see if there is a way to speed up this webcrawler. One way I was thinking was to limit it to only contact pages, but I couldn't figure out a smart way of doing that.

Comment: Out of curiosity--why can't you execute multiple copies of the crawler, instead of one domain at a time?

Comment: Ah thats pretty smart...how would I do that

also I have no idea why this is getting downvoted. Is this not a legitimate question?

Comment: so, let me get this straight. you are asking us to provide you with a better way to collect email addresses that you will use to do... what ? send spam to them ? sell to people who send spam ? You see my problem with your question, right ? I find it shameless to ask that here.

Comment: @Tuncay Göncüoğlu Tons of websites provide email addresses like hunter.io or websitescrape.email - I'm building a crawler that yes one of the things that it gets is email addresses.

Comment: so your argument is "some others are shameless too, so therefore I can be shameless". good one.

Comment: No my argument its not shameless to begin with. You dont even know how Im using the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your intentions are not nefarious--

As mentioned in the comment, one way to achieve this is executing the crawler in parallel (multithreading)---as opposed to doing one domain at a time.

Something like:

```
exec('php crawler.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
exec('php crawler.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
exec('php crawler.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
exec('php crawler.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
exec('php crawler.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

On the server, you can setup a `CRON` job that will do this automatically, so that you are not running it manually.

Comment: Thanks - I am using this to build a better profile of our EXISTING customers of which we have over 50,000 sites to crawl